# Tangent Cone is a cone?

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I first give two definitions.

> **Def1**: A set $S$ is a *cone* if $x \in S, \lambda \geq 0 \implies \lambda x \in S$.
>
> **Def2**: Let $S$ be any set (we may assume $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual Euclidean norm) and $\bar{x} \in S$. The *tangent cone* to $S$ at $\bar{x}$ is defined as
>
> $$T_S(\bar{x}) = \overline{\{ h :  \bar{x} + \lambda h \in S, \text{ for some } \lambda >0\}}$$

Prove that the tangent cone is indeed a cone.

Comment: That definition of the tangent cone does not seem correct to me, actually.  It looks identical to the definition of feasible directions - not the tangent cone.  look here at page 2-7: http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~cmcaram/EE381V_2012F/Lecture_2_Scribe_Notes.final.pdf

Comment: @Sother, we are taking the closure of the set.

Comment: I see.  Another thought:  Cones are not, in general, convex.  So, it makes sense that you actually did not need that property in order to prove this generally for all tangent cones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Proof**: Let $(h^n) \in T_S$, where $h^n \to h$; then we have $\bar{x} + \lambda^n h^n \in S$ for some $(\lambda^n) \geq 0$. Now consider $\gamma \geq 0$, then notice that $\bar{x} + (\lambda^n/\gamma) \gamma h^n \in S$, implying that $(\gamma h^n )\in T_S$. But by definition, $T_S$ is closed, and hence $\gamma h \in T$ proving the statement.

So it was a silly move in the end, and that convexity was not necessary.

Comment: When you say $h^n \rightarrow h$, does that mean a sequence of elements of $T_S$ which converge to $h$?

Comment: @Sother, yes. Since the set is closed, we have this property.

Comment: thanks @Hawk, you are helping me understand this a lot better.  Is that because of the Bolzano-Wierstrass theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano–Weierstrass_theorem) ?  OR is it true that any sequence in a closed set converges to a point in that closed set?  Thanks.  I'm just having some trouble understanding what $(\gamma h^n) \in T_S$ means?  I would have written $(\gamma h^n) \rightarrow \gamma h \in T_S$

Comment: By definition, all convergent sequences inclosed sets contain the limit.

Comment: I see. So a set S is closed IFF all of the limits of convergent sequences in S, are also in S.. In which case, you don't need Bolzano Weirestrass